# Check if url contains ''name.php''

Tags: php

> EDIT : I noticed that when i load content from `fnc/nameload.php`, the REQUEST_URI will return `fnc/nameload.php` because that's where the information is loaded from, even though i'm on `name.php`.

I've read a question about this, but it didn't answer my question so I will ask it myself.

I built a function in JQuery/Ajax that loads specific information from `functions/nameload.php` into a file called `name.php`
Now i want to deny access to function/nameload.php through direct access.

I tried

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "name.php")){
//works
} else {
die("Access denied");
}
```

This did not work, I assume because the '.php' is in the name.

And since 'nameload' contains the word 'name'

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "name")){ //works }else{ die("Access 
Denied");
```

it doesn't deny the access.
Is there a function for checking this?

Comment: (1) do you *only* want to deny access to `nameload.php` or any  PHP script that has `name` in it? (2) What is the exact value of `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` just before the `if`?

Comment: (1)I want to deny access when the url is exactly /nameload.php/ , since the function is loaded from /name.php/

Comment: (1) then why not compare against exactly nameload.php?

Comment: It seems like the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is ''fnc/nameload.php'' even when i'm on the page ''name.php'' because the content is loaded from ''fnc/nameload.php''.. Weird, i'll look into this.

Comment: Direct access means anyone write it in the address bar, then it should be redirected or blocked?

Comment: @Wesley Can you use a `.htaccess` file to block the access to that specific file? Or maybe even place the files to include outside the webroot, where no URL can access them.

Comment: I don't understand what you are after. I would think it is a good thing that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns the address of the request, not of the page. Otherwise you cannot ever include the page! Could you edit your question and clearly explain the behaviour you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a handy function to return different components of your URL: [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

So you can do:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Doing a var_dump on the $url will return an array of values
var_dump(parse_url($url));
```

Comment: I was aware, thanks for sharing. The problem i'm having now is that even when i'm on '' name.php '' the information is loaded from ''fnc/nameload.php'' . As soon as it's loaded, the $url will dump (fnc/nameload.php) even when i'm on ''name.php''

Answer (score 0):

preg_match("/name.php/", url, $match)

strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "name.php") !== false, will work